# Retrieving data from parse.com and displaying in a table layout

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, android-tablelayout

I am able to retrieve the data, according to the logs, but not sure how to display them.  I have created an activity with a table layout and tablerow with a textview to display the categories.

[image: Main Activity]

[image: content_recipes.xml]

Logs:

[image: Logs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to generate a prototype, you can use ParseQueryAdapter.

The code is from Parse.com docs

```
// Inside an Activity
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Uses a layout with a ListView (id: "listview"), which uses our Adapter.
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "Instrument");
  adapter.setTextKey("name");
  adapter.setImageKey("photo");

  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
  listView.setAdapter;
}
```

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#user-interface-parsequeryadapter

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android

You can custom your query by a queryFactory

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#user-interface-customizing-the-query

Or you can custom your XXXAdapter(ListAdapter, ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter).

Before call findInBG show a loading animation. Once done be called, set this list to your adapter, and then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

If you are just not familiar with using ListView, you should Google it.

Answer (score 0):

As I see,  this logs is JSON. May be the better way is use Gson deserialization.

Comment: Not sure what that is but this is the same data I used for iOS and I read somewhere to show it in the logs to use parse interceptor in the  file